# change position of Slide To Cancel

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, quartz-core

I'm using [SlideToCancel](https://github.com/iosdeveloper/SlideToCancel) as per requirements to my project but i'm unable to find how to change the position of button.

I have gone through all the code but cannot figure.
Here is the main code:

## import

```
#import "SlideToCancelViewController.h"

@interface SlideToCancelViewController()

- (void) setGradientLocations:(CGFloat)leftEdge;
- (void) startTimer;
- (void) stopTimer;

@end

static const CGFloat gradientWidth = 0.2;
static const CGFloat gradientDimAlpha = 0.5;
static const int animationFramesPerSec = 8;

@implementation SlideToCancelViewController

@synthesize delegate;

// Implement the "enabled" property
- (BOOL) enabled {
    return slider.enabled;
}

- (void) setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled{
    slider.enabled = enabled;
    label.enabled = enabled;
    if (enabled) {
        slider.value = 0.0;
        label.alpha = 1.0;
        touchIsDown = NO;
        [self startTimer];
    } else {
        [self stopTimer];
    }
}

- (UILabel *)label {
    // Access the view, which will force loadView to be called 
    // if it hasn't already been, which will create the label
    (void)[self view];

    return label;
}

// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
    // Load the track background
    UIImage *trackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderTrack.png"];
    sliderBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:trackImage];

    // Create the superview same size as track backround, and add the background image to it
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sliderBackground.frame];
    [view addSubview:sliderBackground];

    // Add the slider with correct geometry centered over the track
    slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:sliderBackground.frame];
    CGRect sliderFrame = slider.frame;
    sliderFrame.size.width -= 46; //each "edge" of the track is 23 pixels wide
    slider.frame = sliderFrame;
    slider.center = sliderBackground.center;
    slider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [slider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderMaxMin-02.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [slider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderMaxMin-02.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderThumb.png"];
    [slider setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 1.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    slider.value = 0.0;

    // Set the slider action methods
    [slider addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(sliderUp:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [slider addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(sliderDown:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [slider addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(sliderChanged:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    // Create the label with the actual size required by the text
    // If you change the text, font, or font size by using the "label" property,
    // you may need to recalculate the label's frame.
    NSString *labelText = NSLocalizedString(@"slide to cancel", @"SlideToCancel label");
    UIFont *labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
    CGSize labelSize = [labelText sizeWithFont:labelFont];
    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, labelSize.width, labelSize.height)];

    // Center the label over the slidable portion of the track
    CGFloat labelHorizontalCenter = slider.center.x + (thumbImage.size.width / 2);
    label.center = CGPointMake(labelHorizontalCenter, slider.center.y);

    // Set other label attributes and add it to the view
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = labelFont;
    label.text = labelText;
    [view addSubview:label];

    [view addSubview:slider];

    // This property is set to NO (disabled) on creation.
    // The caller must set it to YES to animate the slider.
    // It should be set to NO (disabled) when the view is not visible, in order
    // to turn off the timer and conserve CPU resources.
    self.enabled = NO;

    // Render the label text animation using our custom drawing code in
    // the label's layer.
    label.layer.delegate = self;

    // Set the view controller's view property to all of the above
    self.view = view;

    // The view is retained by the superclass, so release our copy
    [view release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    [self stopTimer];
    [sliderBackground release], sliderBackground = nil;
    [slider release], slider = nil;
    [label release], label = nil;
}

// UISlider actions
- (void) sliderUp: (UISlider *) sender
{
    //filter out duplicate sliderUp events
    if (touchIsDown) {
        touchIsDown = NO;

        if (slider.value != 1.0)  //if the value is not the max, slide this bad boy back to zero
        {
            [slider setValue: 0 animated: YES];
            label.alpha = 1.0;
            [self startTimer];
        }
        else {
            //tell the delagate we are slid all the way to the right
            [delegate cancelled];
        }
    }
}

- (void) sliderDown: (UISlider *) sender
{
    touchIsDown = YES;
}

- (void) sliderChanged: (UISlider *) sender
{
    // Fade the text as the slider moves to the right. This code makes the
    // text totally dissapear when the slider is 35% of the way to the right.
    label.alpha = MAX(0.0, 1.0 - (slider.value * 3.5));

    // Stop the animation if the slider moved off the zero point
    if (slider.value != 0) {
        [self stopTimer];
        [label.layer setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

// animationTimer methods
- (void)animationTimerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer {
    // Let the timer run for 2 * FPS rate before resetting.
    // This gives one second of sliding the highlight off to the right, plus one
    // additional second of uniform dimness
    if (++animationTimerCount == (2 * animationFramesPerSec)) {
        animationTimerCount = 0;
    }

    // Update the gradient for the next frame
    [self setGradientLocations:((CGFloat)animationTimerCount/(CGFloat)animationFramesPerSec)];
}

- (void) startTimer {
    if (!animationTimer) {
        animationTimerCount = 0;
        [self setGradientLocations:0];
        animationTimer = [[NSTimer 
                           scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/animationFramesPerSec 
                           target:self 
                           selector:@selector(animationTimerFired:) 
                           userInfo:nil 
                           repeats:YES] retain];
    }
}

- (void) stopTimer {
    if (animationTimer) {
        [animationTimer invalidate];
        [animationTimer release], animationTimer = nil;
    }
}

// label's layer delegate method
- (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)theLayer
        inContext:(CGContextRef)theContext
{
    // Set the font
    const char *labelFontName = [label.font.fontName UTF8String];

    // Note: due to use of kCGEncodingMacRoman, this code only works with Roman alphabets! 
    // In order to support non-Roman alphabets, you need to add code generate glyphs,
    // and use CGContextShowGlyphsAtPoint
    CGContextSelectFont(theContext, labelFontName, label.font.pointSize, kCGEncodingMacRoman);

    // Set Text Matrix
    CGAffineTransform xform = CGAffineTransformMake(1.0,  0.0,
                                                    0.0, -1.0,
                                                    0.0,  0.0);
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(theContext, xform);

    // Set Drawing Mode to clipping path, to clip the gradient created below
    CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (theContext, kCGTextClip);

    // Draw the label's text
    const char *text = [label.text cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
    CGContextShowTextAtPoint(
        theContext, 
        0, 
        (size_t)label.font.ascender,
        text, 
        strlen(text));

    // Calculate text width
    CGPoint textEnd = CGContextGetTextPosition(theContext);

    // Get the foreground text color from the UILabel.
    // Note: UIColor color space may be either monochrome or RGB.
    // If monochrome, there are 2 components, including alpha.
    // If RGB, there are 4 components, including alpha.
    CGColorRef textColor = label.textColor.CGColor;
    const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(textColor);
    size_t numberOfComponents = CGColorGetNumberOfComponents(textColor);
    BOOL isRGB = (numberOfComponents == 4);
    CGFloat red = components[0];
    CGFloat green = isRGB ? components[1] : components[0];
    CGFloat blue = isRGB ? components[2] : components[0];
    CGFloat alpha = isRGB ? components[3] : components[1];

    // The gradient has 4 sections, whose relative positions are defined by
    // the "gradientLocations" array:
    // 1) from 0.0 to gradientLocations[0] (dim)
    // 2) from gradientLocations[0] to gradientLocations[1] (increasing brightness)
    // 3) from gradientLocations[1] to gradientLocations[2] (decreasing brightness)
    // 4) from gradientLocations[3] to 1.0 (dim)
    size_t num_locations = 3;

    // The gradientComponents array is a 4 x 3 matrix. Each row of the matrix
    // defines the R, G, B, and alpha values to be used by the corresponding
    // element of the gradientLocations array
    CGFloat gradientComponents[12];
    for (int row = 0; row < num_locations; row++) {
        int index = 4 * row;
        gradientComponents[index++] = red;
        gradientComponents[index++] = green;
        gradientComponents[index++] = blue;
        gradientComponents[index] = alpha * gradientDimAlpha;
    }

    // If animating, set the center of the gradient to be bright (maximum alpha)
    // Otherwise it stays dim (as set above) leaving the text at uniform
    // dim brightness
    if (animationTimer) {
        gradientComponents[7] = alpha;
    }

    // Load RGB Colorspace
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create Gradient
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents (colorspace, gradientComponents,
                                                                  gradientLocations, num_locations);
    // Draw the gradient (using label text as the clipping path)
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient (theContext, gradient, label.bounds.origin, textEnd, 0);

    // Cleanup
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
}

- (void) setGradientLocations:(CGFloat) leftEdge {
    // Subtract the gradient width to start the animation with the brightest 
    // part (center) of the gradient at left edge of the label text
    leftEdge -= gradientWidth;

    //position the bright segment of the gradient, keeping all segments within the range 0..1
    gradientLocations[0] = leftEdge < 0.0 ? 0.0 : (leftEdge > 1.0 ? 1.0 : leftEdge);
    gradientLocations[1] = MIN(leftEdge + gradientWidth, 1.0);
    gradientLocations[2] = MIN(gradientLocations[1] + gradientWidth, 1.0);

    // Re-render the label text
    [label.layer setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [self stopTimer];
    [self viewDidUnload];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Sorry for posting heavy code stuff.

P.S.: I know AppStore doesn't accepts this code but i'm interested to learn & do more on QuartzCore graphics than using interface builders.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25894355/1344237

You have to remove the label.layer.delegate = self;