# UILabel causes app to crash when added to view (Xcode 6 and iOS 8 only)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios8

I have transitioned my project to Xcode 6 in order to build for iOS 8. However, a particular UILabel is causing the app to crash when it is added to the view hierarchy.  This is the only error log I receive:

```
-[MyViewController _contentInsetsFromFonts]: unrecognized selector sent to instance     0x16d90da0
```

I have been unable to locate the `contentInsetsFromFonts` method anywhere in my project.  Additionally, I have not even been able to find a reference for it anywhere online, including Apple's documentation.  I am not using a NIB for this UIViewController so the UI is built in the `loadView` method:

```
- (void)loadView {
    UIImage *trackImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderTrack.png"];
    sliderBackground = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:trackImage];
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sliderBackground.frame];
    [view addSubview:sliderBackground];

    slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:sliderBackground.frame];
    CGRect sliderFrame = slider.frame;
    sliderFrame.size.width -= 46; 
    slider.frame = sliderFrame;
    slider.center = sliderBackground.center;
    slider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [slider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderMaxMinTrackImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [slider setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"sliderMaxMinTrackImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel-slider.png"];
    [slider setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    slider.minimumValue = 0.0;
    slider.maximumValue = 1.0;
    slider.continuous = YES;
    slider.value = 0.0;

    // Set the slider action methods
    [slider addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(sliderUp:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [slider addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(sliderDown:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [slider addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(sliderChanged:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];    

    NSString *labelText = @"label text";
    UIFont *labelFont;
    NSString *osVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    if ([osVersion floatValue] >= 7.0) {
        labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];

    } else {
        labelFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0];
    }

    CGSize labelSize = [labelText sizeWithAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:labelFont, NSFontAttributeName, nil]];

    label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, labelSize.width, labelSize.height)];

    CGFloat labelHorizontalCenter = slider.center.x + (thumbImage.size.width / 2);
    label.center = CGPointMake(labelHorizontalCenter, slider.center.y);

    // Set other label attributes and add it to the view
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = labelFont;
    label.text = labelText;

    [view addSubview:label];

    [view addSubview:slider];

    label.layer.delegate = self;

    self.view = view;
}
```

The app does not crash at `[view addSubview:label]`; it crashes after the `loadView` method returns.

Comment: What did u do to fix it?

Comment: Just deleted the "label.layer.delegate = self" line. I actually have not looked for a replacement because it's a pretty low-priority UI element for me right now. Sorry about that.

Comment: i guess you are embedding SlideToCancelViewController. I found another better class.

Comment: @Enkidu and the better class was/is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [the `UIView` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/layer):

> Never change the delegate of this layer object.

Delete this line:

```
label.layer.delegate = self;
```

Whatever you're trying to accomplish here, you'll need to do in another way.

Comment: is there any replacement?

Comment: but it's also written in CALayerDelegate reference : "The CALayerDelegate informal protocol is implemented by the layer’s delegate to respond to layer-related events. You can implement the methods of this protocol to provide the layer’s content, handle the layout of sublayers, and provide custom animation actions to perform. The object that implements this protocol must be assigned to the delegate property of the layer object."
So what the hell !

Comment: more over : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/SettingUpLayerObjects/SettingUpLayerObjects.html

Comment: @Vassily Sure, but the `UILabel` is already doing that in this case.

Comment: so I need to subclass uilabel and override - (void)drawLayer:(CALayer *)layer inContext:(CGContextRef)context

Comment: @Vassily I have no idea what you're trying to do so I can't say. You may want to post a new question, linking to this one.

Comment: @AaronBrager perfect solution. Thanks